# Automatically change div after window width change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Im stuck on a problem. 
I made two types of tooltipster script. One loads if the screen is less then 1500 screen width and the other if it is bigger. It works fine on first load of the page, but I would like the script to check this width all the time (even after the page has loaded) and if the width of the screen goes below 1500 then activate the appropriate tooltipster.  How to do it?

I tried with setInterval, the algorithm works but eventually it does not change the tooltipster once loaded.

```
    if ($(window).width() < 1500) {
                             $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.tooltip2').tooltipster({
                            animation:'grow', <!--fade, grow, swing, slide, fall--> 
                            theme:'tooltipster-vrijeme',
                            position:'top',
                            offsetX: 10,
                            content: $('<span> <a> xy</a> </span>')
        });}); 

                            ;}
                            else {
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.tooltip2').tooltipster({
                                position:'left',
                            animation:'grow', <!--fade, grow, swing, slide, fall--> 
                            theme:'tooltipster-vrijeme',
                            position:'left',
                            offsetX: 10,
                            content: $('<span> <a> xy</a> </span>')
        }); });
                            ;}
```

Comment: Why not just do media queries? (responsive CSS)

Comment: Why not just do media queries?x2 Anyway, you can make a function triggered by [**onresize event**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp)

Comment: Obviously, the `if($window).width()` code will execute before either of the `$(document).ready()` functions, but you'd want `$(document).ready` to run before any other code. So, what you have essentially says "After the page is loaded, decide what to do as soon as the page is loaded."